# Why does cross-multiplication not work with modulus?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

I want to find whether the statement $(a/b)modp < (c)modp$ holds true or false **without calculating the multiplicative inverse of b** (as it's a very costly procedure when the size of b increases around 500 bits). Workaround I thought was to cross multiply and check if `(a)modp < (b*c)modp`. But it is not showing consistency...
Consider mod 7.
 Consider $(5/3)mod7 < 4$
=$(5*5)mod7 < 4$ (inverse of 3=5 as (3*5)mod7=1)
=$4 < 4$ which is **false**.
Now consider $5 < (3*4)mod7$
=$5 < 5$ which is **false**
Now consider $(1/3)mod7 < 3$
=$(1*5)mod7 < 3$
=$5 < 3$ which is **false**
Now consider $1 < (3*3)mod7$
=$1 < 2$ which is **true**!! 
Is this method wrong? If yes, why is it wrong? I imagine it should have not caused any problems!! Also, what else i can do to check whether `(a/b)modp < (c)modp` holds true or false **without calculating the multiplicative inverse of b**?
**UPDATE!!**--- Assume $c=(p+1)/2$. What can i do for this special condition?
**Other examples..**
Consider $(3/2)mod7>4$
The right way to do this is to calculate the inverse of 2.
$=(3*4)mod7>4$
$=5>4$ which is **true**
Now consider cross multiplication
$3>(4*2)mod7 = 3>1$ which is **true**.
What this can mean is that instead of finding the inverse which is very time consuming when the no of bits exceed 500, i can just cross-multiply and then compare as i get the same result.
Consider $(3/5)mod7 > 4$
$=(3*3)mod7>4$
$=2>4$ which is **false**
Now consider cross-multiplication
$=3>(4*5)mod7$
$3>6$ which is **false**. So, cross multiplication seems like its working.. But no!!
Consider $(5/4)mod7 > 4$
$=(5*2)mod7 > 4$
$=3 > 4$ which is **false**
Now, consider cross-multiplication
$=5 > (4*4)mod7$
$=5 > 2$ which is **true**!!
See the discrepancy here.. Is this method wrong? What else can i do? Am i missing a minor detail here and this method here can give the right answers?

Comment: You can't use > or > in modulo calculation, 3=-3mod 7 so 3>-3?

Comment: @trula Thanks for the reply. What can i do then to check whether (a/b)modp < (c)modp holds true or false without calculating the multiplicative inverse of b?

Comment: @trula also, 3 is not equal to -3mod7 as -3mod7=4

Comment: This looks like you're using a computer science way of thinking about mod, which might be causing some confusion. As @trula said, order relations are meaningless for mod in a mathematical sense. Maybe to clear things up you could give some examples of how you would like the comparison to work?

Comment: @ChrisLewis Consider the example given above with (1/3)mod7<3. The right answer here is false as i get the answer by calculating the multiplicative inverse of 3. I want to arrive at the result =false without calculating the multiplicative inverse of 3. So i tried cross-multiplying. I expected it to give correct answer but it didn't and now im confused

Comment: @ChrisLewis So now, What can i do then to check whether (a/b)modp < (c)modp holds true or false without calculating the multiplicative inverse of b?

Comment: OK. My suggestion is that you give further examples showing how you want it to work, with an explanation. There's not much point repeating an example you already gave but without any explanation! Is your point that because the real number $\frac13$ is less than the real number $3$, that should also hold mod $7$?

Comment: @ChrisLewis First, lets work on a special case. Assume c=(p-1)/2. What can i do then? I have Updated the question below..

Comment: @ChrisLewis Sure. Give me 10 minutes.. Ill update other examples

Comment: @ChrisLewis (1/3) when applied in field 7 is (1*5)=5

Comment: Some how you can not accept that there are local field s like in the modulo which are not orderd, so there exists no < or > for modulo. I made a mistake with 3=-3 so 3=-4 but still -4<3 makes no sense, since -4=3 mod 7, its similar  to people in a circle , compared with people in a row,  in a row you can say who ist before  an other Person, in a circle you can not . the number 0 to 6 in mod  are arranged like in a circle after 6 the 0 comes again , so you can not say 3 is before (or smaller) than 4. For what do you need this comparison?

Comment: @ChrisLewis I have updated other examples.. Hope it helps

Comment: @trula What else can i do then? Also, i have updated the question with a special condition and other examples to help. Assume c=(p+1)/2. Any way then?

Comment: @trula I am working on elliptic points on secp256k1 curve. I need to compare the y-values of inverse points. I have the coordinates in projective form

Comment: Thanks for the updates. As far as I can see, the issue is you are actually interested in a different (but similar) function (the computer science one). For positive integers $a,p$, define $M(a,p)=a-p\left\lfloor \frac{a}{p} \right\rfloor$. (This is basically the MOD() function in Excel.) Then it *does* make sense to talk about orderings.

Comment: @trula instead of dividing y-coordinate with z and then comparing with (p+1)/2 since the sum of inverse points always adds up to p, im looking for a way to get the answer without finding the multiplicative inverse cuz that defeats the purpose of projective coordinates

Comment: @ChrisLewis Ok you mean to say that there is no order available for substitution?

Comment: @trula I get the circle analogy. From one value to another, there are two paths. How about this? a is consider to be greater than b if the abs(clockwise path) < abs(anti-clockwise path). Or any metric designed for comparison purposes.. How can that be calculated? Cuz (a/b)modp has a single positive value < p. (c)modp has a positive value < p. I'm just comparing two +ve values. So, there is one right answer for the given conditions!

Comment: As a general rule, problems in modular arithmetic which require using the single positive value < p tend not to have nice solutions.

Comment: Related to a previous question [Find which number is greater over modulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4707886/89922)?

Comment: As you might have noticed, because multiplying both sides by the same number does not (always) preserve the order: $1< 4$, but
$$\underbrace{(1\cdot 2)\bmod 7}_{=2} \not< \underbrace{(4\cdot 2)\bmod 7}_{=1}$$

Comment: PLease do not duplicate your [prior questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4739303/242)